# Does distance of one user from WiFi AP have negative impact on other connected users?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

One of my friends (that knows very well Wireless world) told me following:

Consider we have high speed AP. If one user stays out of the range of AP WiFi (lets say 51 meter away) - he will have low throughput **and therefore all users that connected to the same AP will suffer from low traffic.**

Is it true?

Comment: @Jeroen3 thank you, will move it to  networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. All of the communications between the AP and that user will take up more air time as the data rate will be lower. There could also be issues with collisions if the users are too far apart from each other to reliably pick up each other's transmissions and back off to avoid collisions. But the other users should not see any major change in data rate as the rate negotiation is done on a per-device basis.